# How to get IP of the client?

Tags: servicestack

I've wrote a self-hosted servicestack server and a client, both desktop applications.
In my very basic PING test service I'm trying to retrieve the IP of the client.
Server is on 192.168.0.87:82, client I tried on the same computer and on another computer, but RemoteIp and UserHostAddress always return 192.168.0.87:82. XRealIp is null.
I also tried base.Request.RemoteIp, but still is 192.168.0.87:82.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public RespPing Any(ReqPing request)
    {
        string IP = base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().RemoteIp;
        string MAC = request.iTransactionInfo.MAC;

        Log(MAC,IP, base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().RemoteIp + base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().XRealIp + base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().UserHostAddress);

        RespPing response = new RespPing { Result = "PONG" };

        return response;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Request.RemoteIp` works for me

Comment: I believe that was a recently fixed bug: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/f7d2365bf9a115d45f9a774aefa8ed2226abe943

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Made it with:

```
HttpListenerRequest iHttpListenerRequest = (HttpListenerRequest)base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().OriginalRequest;

string IP = iHttpListenerRequest.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0];
```

`Request.RemoteIP` kept giving me the server address.

Comment: Btw you can use here type inference and just write: 
`var iHttpListenerRequest = (HttpListenerRequest)base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().OriginalRequest;`

Answer (score 3):

ServiceStack.4.0.38

string IP = base.Request.RemoteIp;

Answer (score 2):

fwiw I had to do something just a little bit different:

```
HttpListenerRequest iHttpListenerRequest = (HttpListenerRequest)base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().OriginalRequest;
string ip = iHttpListenerRequest.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString();
```